# Assign non-generic type to a generic type atribute

Tags: swift, generic-programming

Consider the following class of a generic dictionary:

```
class GenericDictionaryClass<Key:Hashable,Value> : NSCoding{

    var internalDictionary = Dictionary<Key,Value>.init()

    public init(){

    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        let uncodeDictionary = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "internalDictionary") as! Dictionary<Key, Value>

        var newDictionary = Dictionary<Key,(Double,Double)>.init()

        for(key,tuple) in uncodeDictionary{

            var newTuple = tuple as! Tuple
            newDictionary[key] = (newTuple.firstValue,newTuple.secondValue)

        }

        self.internalDictionary = newDictionary ← ERROR!

    }

}
```

Im trying to modify the class atribute `internalDictionary` with a non generic type, and it's returning this error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'Dictionary' to type 
>   'Dictionary<*,*>'

Im trying to do this because my generic dictionary class confirms to nscoding protocol, this way i can encode and decode it. I've removed the encode function, because i have already tested it and it's working as it should. My problem is when i try to decode the dictionary. The dictionary value is a swift tuple `(,)`, so when I encode it, I need to transform it on something else, because swift does not encode tuples. So I created a class Tuple where i store my tuples to encode it, and when i decode them, I'm manually transforming this Tuple's back to the swift tuple.

```
public class Tuple : NSObject, NSCoding{

    var firstValue : Double
    var secondValue : Double

    init(firstValue : Double, secondValue : Double) {
        self.firstValue = firstValue
        self.secondValue = secondValue
        super.init()
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.firstValue = aDecoder.decodeDouble(forKey: "firstValue")
        self.secondValue = aDecoder.decodeDouble(forKey: "secondValue")
    }

    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(firstValue, forKey: "firstValue")
        aCoder.encode(secondValue, forKey: "secondValue")
    }


}
```

I decode the dictionary, create a new one, transform all Tuples to Swift type, but when i finally will set the `internalDictionary` with the `newDictionary` it throws the error. Someone know how to resolve it?

Comment: I haven't yet understood what you are trying to achieve and how the problem is related to NSCoding and tuples. But the above code cannot work. If you have created a `let genDict = GenericDictionaryClass<Int, Float>()` then what do you expect that `genDict.modifyParameter()` does? It cannot change the type of the internalDictionary property to `Dictionary<String,Int>`.

Comment: Im implementing the GenericDictionaryClass initializer to decode the internalDictionary that was previously encoded (`init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`). But when i retrieve the encoded dictionary with the function `decodeObject`, as i had transformed all Swift tuples `(Double,Double)` into a class named Tuple to encode it, the Value from this dictionary is from Tuple class. So i need to transform it back into swift tuples, making Tuple → (Double,Double).

Comment: The problem is that when i make this cast manually, i have a new Dictionary<Key,(Double,Double)> (the Key remains the same), and i have to assert this new Dictionary to the GenericDictionaryClass atribute internalDictionary. But this atribute is marked as <Key,Value>, not <Key,(Double,Double)>, and thats what im trying to turn around. Summarizing, when i've encoded `internalDictionary` i have transformed (Double,Double) into Tuple.

Comment: Now i need to reverse it, but it's not possible to assign a non-generic value, `Dictionary<Key,(Double,Double)` to a generic one `Dictionary<Key,Value>`. If i couldn't be clear please let me know.